# Keycloak start failed: org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation.microprofile-context-propagation-api-1.2.jar does not exist

Tags: keycloak

I follow this Keycloak [guide](https://www.keycloak.org/getting-started/getting-started-zip) to start Keycloak on my server. I am receiving the next exception when running the `bin/kc.sh start-dev` command:

```
ERROR: Failed to run 'build' command.
ERROR: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: /srv/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation.microprofile-context-propagation-api-1.2.jar does not exist
ERROR: /srv/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation.microprofile-context-propagation-api-1.2.jar does not exist
ERROR: /srv/keycloak/lib/lib/main/org.eclipse.microprofile.context-propagation.microprofile-context-propagation-api-1.2.jar
For more details run the same command passing the '--verbose' option. Also you can use '--help' to see the details about the usage of the particular command.
```

The Keycloak version is `18.0.1`, the installed JDK version is `11.0.15`, the OS is `Debian 11`

Can anyone tell me how to solve it? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that some of the `jar`s were missing after extracting the loaded  Keycloak `18.0.2` tar.gz file on the server. After replacing the `jar`s under `keycloak/lib/lib/main` and `keycloak/lib/lib/deployment` I was able to start the Keycloak. To do that, I extracted Keycloak `18.0.2` tar.gz on my local machine and uploaded corresponding `jar`s to the server machine.  [image]
[image]

Comment: I found TAR file had name trimmed, causing problem. I downloaded ZIP file instead and got it working.